# Is the time complexity of this mergesort implementation O(nlogn)?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, mergesort

In this online textbook https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html they give the following code for mergesort:

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] <= righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
```

In the analysis the online book makes they write:

> Recall that the slicing operator is O(k) where k is the size of the slice. In order to guarantee that mergeSort will be O(nlogn) we will need to remove the slice operator.Again, this is possible if we simply pass the starting and ending indices along with the list when we make the recursive call.

So my first question is:

1- Can you guys tell me of a scenario where the slice operators would ruin the time complexity of the algorithm?

I wrote the code to do it without a slice operation below:

```
def mergeSort2(alist, l, r):
    if r - l >= 1:
        mid = l + (r - l)//2

        mergeSort2(alist, l, mid)
        mergeSort2(alist, mid+1, r)

        i = l
        j = mid+1
        k = 0
        temp_list = [None]*(r-l+1)
        while i < mid+1 and j < r+1:
            if alist[i] <= alist[j]:
                temp_list[k] = alist[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                temp_list[k] = alist[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < mid+1:
            temp_list[k] = alist[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < r+1:
            temp_list[k] = alist[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

        n = 0
        for index in range(l,r+1):
            alist[index] = temp_list[n]
            n += 1
```

As you can see the loop at the bottom of the code could be replaced with a slice.

Question 2:

2- The way I see it instead of doing 2 slices that take `k` time before the recursive calls we are now initialising `temp_list` in `k` time and then copying the sorted `temp_list` into our result in `k` time. So the time complexity of the algorithm has not changed?

Comment: The slices are fine. They're not hurting the time complexity at all.

Comment: What about my rewrite, what would be the advantage/con of doing it the way I did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing shouldn't affect the time complexity at all in terms of it's order of magnitude. The constant factor is another discussion.

The key part of understanding how the time complexity is unchanged is here:

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)
```

So let's break it down step by step:

Here we copy the entire list. This is `O(N)`

```
lefthalf = alist[:mid]
righthalf = alist[mid:]
```

This part calls `mergeSort` on the left and the right, leading to recursive slicing.

```
mergeSort(lefthalf)
mergeSort(righthalf)
```

`mergeSort(lefthalf)` and `mergeSort(righthalf)` together will slice the entirety of the array, and the sum of their recursive children will do so as well. The thing is the number of times the array is sliced in it's entirety is `log N`, since you keep dividing the array by 2 and you can only do that `log N` times. This gives you `O(N)` slice times `O(log N)` times you do the slice resulting in `O(NlogN)`

To summarize:

1. No if the slicing is implemented correctly. Obviously you can add random slices and mess up the time complexity.
2. Slicing won't change the magnitude of your time complexity - still `O(NlogN)`